# Visual Studio Code - All white text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently my visual studio code's text has all been white and I cannot change it with the 'File > Preferences > Color Theme' options. This is not a problem on my laptop, which still has multicolored code.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Here's a picture of what it looks like]

Comment: Can you provide more details for better help you. Should you read first '[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)'.

Comment: which language is this?

Comment: It is showing as white text because it is defaulting to plain text as shown in the bottom right corner. You have to check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview. If it doesnt exist, look for an extension for your language

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's set as plain text as you can see in the bottom right corner. You have to save it as one of VS Code's given file extensions or you have to download a extensions for your programming language.

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom right side of your vs code there will be plaine text click on that it will show different language select a language in which your code is written after the colour will automatically applied

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see the blue bar at the bottom which is the status bar and at the rightmost side it shows that your file is saved as a *Plain Text* file. Click there and you can select a language for your file from the appearing list.
For example, if you select Python it will be changed as Python file and then you should be able to execute it.